# How do I iterate through array and set classes individually?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a jquery plugin which generates dynamic lists out of whatever data I send in. Now, the 6 first items will at all times be the same, despite data I send.

By *same* I mean they have different values than the others, but these values will never change.

```
sample: item 1, item 2, item 3... item 6 > item 87, item 77
```

These first 6 items I want to grant different CSS styles, but I can't seem to catch the individual object to do so.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.addStyles = function () {
        // As the items gets listed in UL LI tags, I take the LI tags using .children()
        var $children = this.children(); 
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I iterate through this collection of objects and individually add CSS styles?

Thank you.

Comment: check my answer - another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate - you can use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('#list').children('li').slice(0, 6).addClass('oneOfTheFirstSix')
```

If your condition becomes more complex, you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('#list').children('li').filter(function(n) {
    return n % 3 == 0;
}).addClass('everyThirdElement')
```

---

From your updated question, does this do what you want?

```
var listItems = $('#list').children('li');

listItems.eq(0).addClass('theFirstClass');
listItems.eq(1).addClass('theSecondClass');
listItems.eq(2).addClass('the3rdClass');
listItems.eq(3).addClass('the4thClass');
listItems.eq(4).addClass('thePenultimateClass');
listItems.eq(5).addClass('theLastClass');
```

Comment: I think he wants to put it in the plugin so he have to use some kind of this....no ?

Comment: I'm sure @Ziga is capable of replacing `$('#list')` with `this` if they want to. I'm not sure this warrants a plugin anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This only applies 1 style for all 6. What I want to achieve is add one unique style to each of the 6 items. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear enough in my post.

Comment: @Ziga: What are the classes you want to apply? How are they named?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need :

http://jsbin.com/evaxaj/4/edit

```
 (function ($)
  {
     $.fn.addStyles = function ()
     {
        return this.each(function (i, n)
        {
           if (i < 1) //change to 6 or...
           $(this).css('color', 'red');
        });
     }
  })(jQuery);
  $('a').addStyles();
```

Comment: Could you do a worse job of indenting that?